# Class doesnt exist

Tags: symfony

i tried this method implementing a repository and i get this error: Class "App:Product" doesn't exist, even though the ide suggested i put it in the method getRepository().
here's the code:

```php
/**
* @Route("/list", name= "Product")
*/
public function index(ManagerRegistry $doctrine): Response 
{
    $repository=$doctrine->getRepository('Product:class');
    $products=$repository->findAll();
    return $this->render('product/index.html.twig',[
       'products'=>$products
    ]);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Following the doc, you better use a non string class identifier and add a use statement to import the product class.

```php
// ...
$products = $doctrine->getRepository(Product::class)->findAll();
```

https://symfony.com/doc/5.4/doctrine.html#fetching-objects-from-the-database

You can also inject the repository itself in your method

```php
public function index(ProductRepository $productRepository): Response {
//...
```

Comment: i get the same error, the class still is recognizable. and what do you mean by injecting the repository the problem is in the persistent object it tells me that it doesnt exist

Comment: By injecting the repository you'll not have to use the `ManagerRegistry` to get the repository. Do you have a `Product` class in your `Entity` folder ?

Comment: yes i have an entity called Product

Comment: And do you have the right `use` statement ?

Comment: if you mean the use statement in the productController yes its : use Doctrine\Persistence\ManagerRegistry;

Comment: No: `use App\Entity\Product;` That's the Product class that is not found, not the registry

Comment: yea i have that use :((

Comment: can you please update your question with your full controller code, your product entity code, and your directory structure ?